# I can't style the mobile view on tumblr

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

I'm a less than an amateur coder I've just been using tumblr as a photo journal/portfolio and running into some styling trouble and hoping to find some assistance. I've been able to modify the theme I'm using to get the desktop view how I'd like but the mobile view still has some elements I'd like to remove.

While in the mobile view between each photo there's meta data on the post above it. I'd like to remove the the meta data and close the gap between the photos. I've tried adding `display:none !important;` under `.post-meta, .meta, .share` but it results in no changes.

I'm not sure which part of the code to show for a proper diagnosis so I've placed the entire theme's code below. Any help is appreciated.

[francis.gallery](https://francis.gallery)

Tumblr Theme:

```
<style type="text/css">
    
    @media (min-width:740px) {
        .tmblr-iframe--unified-controls {
            z-index: 999999999 !important;
        }
    }
    
    .post-navigation .stash-close-btn {
        position: initial !important;
        top: initial !important;
        left: initial !important;
    }
    
    @media (min-width:740px) {
body {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}


    body {
        font: {text:Font Size} {block:IfBodyFont}"{text:Body Font}",{/block:IfBodyFont} "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        {block:IfTypeKitBodyFont}
            font:{text:Font Size} "{text:TypeKit Body Font}", "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        {/block:IfTypeKitBodyFont}
        color: {color:Text};
        font-weight:{select:Body Font Weight};
        line-height:1.6;
        background: {color:Background} url({image:Background}) 
            {block:ifrepeatbackgroundimage}repeat fixed;{/block:ifrepeatbackgroundimage}
            {block:ifnotrepeatbackgroundimage}no-repeat center fixed; background-size:cover; -webkit-background-size:cover{/block:ifnotrepeatbackgroundimage}
        ;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        overflow-y:auto;
    }
    
    {block:ifnotscrollbar}
        @media (min-width:740px) {
            ::-webkit-scrollbar {
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                display: none; 
            }
        }
    {/block:ifnotscrollbar}

    blockquote {
        font:{text:Font Size} {block:IfBodyFont}"{text:Body Font}",{/block:IfBodyFont} "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Times New Roman, sans-serif;
        {block:IfTypeKitBodyFont}
            font:{text:Font Size} "{text:TypeKit Body Font}", "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        {/block:IfTypeKitBodyFont}
        padding: 0;
        font-style:italic;
    }

    
    .wrapper {
        background: {color:Background} url({image:Background}) 
            {block:ifrepeatbackgroundimage}repeat fixed;{/block:ifrepeatbackgroundimage}
            {block:ifnotrepeatbackgroundimage}no-repeat center fixed; background-size:cover; -webkit-background-size:cover{/block:ifnotrepeatbackgroundimage}
        ;
    }

    .button {
        padding: 8px 13px;
        color:{color:Background};
        background:{color:Accent};
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-family:{block:IfBodyFont}"{text:Body Font}",{/block:IfBodyFont} "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Times New Roman, sans-serif;
        {block:IfTypeKitBodyFont}
            font-family:"{text:TypeKit Body Font}", "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        {/block:IfTypeKitBodyFont}
        text-transform:uppercase;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;
        transition:all 0.2s ease-out;
        cursor:pointer;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;
        margin-top:15px;
    }
    
    .banner-button {
        background:{color:Banner Button Background};
        color:{color:Banner Button Text} !important;
    }

    .banner-button:first-of-type {
        margin:0 14px 0 0;
    }      
    

    .stash-content .post-answer {
        border: 5px solid {color:Accent};
    }

    /* Global styles */
    
    a, .post-like, #backToTop {
        color: {color:Accent};
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    a:hover, .post-like:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
        color:{color:Text};
    }
    
    h1 a,h2 a,h3 a,h4 a,h5 a,h6 a {
        color:{color:Accent};
    }
    
    .footer-icon {
        color: {color:Text};
    }
    
    .post-photo {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .post-quote blockquote, .quote blockquote {
        border:none;
        padding:0;
        font-size:24px;
        font-weight:700;
        line-height:1.3;
        color: {color:Accent};
    }
    
    .meta a:hover, .tags a:hover, .share.permalink li:hover {
        border-bottom: 1px solid {color:Accent};
    }
    
    #header {
        color:{color:Header Text};
        background:{color:Header Background};
    }
    
    /*Custom CSS*/
    {CustomCSS}
    
    .note-count, #stash-ants .meta, #stash-ants .post-meta .share, .meta, .share {
            display:none !important;
        }
    
    .share li a {
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    
    .post-page .asker-box {
        border-left: 5px solid {color:Accent};
        border-top: 5px solid {color:Accent};
    }
    
    .asker-box {
        background:{color:Accent};
        padding:8px;
        color:{color:Background};
    }
    
    .asker {
        color:{color:Background};
    }
    
    article.post.pp .post-header {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:24px;
        visibility:hidden;
        opacity:0;
        color:#E7E7E7;
        z-index:3;
        font-size:16px;
        cursor:url("https://static.tumblr.com/evx2wil/6N2o49gaj/plus.svg"),auto;
        cursor:-webkit-image-set(url("https://static.tumblr.com/evx2wil/6N2o49gaj/plus.svg")),auto;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-5px,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,-5px,0);
    }
    article.post.pp:hover .post-header {
        opacity:1;
        visibility:visible;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    }
    
    {block:IfNotShowPostNoteCount}
        .post-note-count, .meta-notes {
            display:none !important;
        }
    {/block:IfNotShowPostNoteCount}
    
    .post-header a {
        color:#fff;
        font-size:16px;
        display:block;
        cursor:url("https://static.tumblr.com/evx2wil/6N2o49gaj/plus.svg"),auto;
        cursor:-webkit-image-set(url("https://static.tumblr.com/evx2wil/6N2o49gaj/plus.svg")),auto;
    }
    
    #sidebar {
        color:{color:Header Text};
        background:{color:Header Background};
    }
    
    #sidebar {
        font-size:{text:Sidebar Text Size};
    }

    #sidebar h3 {
        font-size:{text:Sidebar Title Text Size};
    }
    
    .search input {
        border: none;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background:transparent;
        background: {color:Header Text};
        color: {color:Header Background};
        text-align:left;
        font-family: {block:IfBodyFont}"{text:Body Font}",{/block:IfBodyFont} "{select:Font}", 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
        -webkit-transition: .2s;
        transition: .2s;
        font-size: 13px;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        padding: 8px 14px;
    }
    .search input[type="submit"] {
        background:{color:Header Background};
        color:{color:Header Text};
        text-transform:uppercase;
        padding:10px 0;
        text-align:center;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    
    .search input::placeholder {
      color: {color:Header Background};   
      opacity:0.8;
    }
    .search input::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
      color: {color:Header Background};
      opacity:0.8;
    }
    :.search input:-moz-placeholder { 
      color: {color:Header Background};
      opacity:0.8;
    }
    .search input:-ms-input-placeholder {
      color: {color:Header Background};
      opacity:0.8;
    }
    .search input:-moz-placeholder {
      color: {color:Header Background};
      opacity:0.8;
    }
    
    #sidebar a {
        color:{color:Header Text};
    }
    .widget h3 {
        color:{color:Header Text};
    }
    
    .widget {
        color:{color:Header Text};
    }

    #twitter a {
        color:{color:Header Text};
    }
    .social-links ul li a {
        color:{color:Header Text};
    }
    

    /* Modal */

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        
        .stash-content.big-height {
            top: 0;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
            transform: translate(-50%, 0);
            -webkit-transition: top .4s, left .4s, right .4s, transform .4s, width .4s;
            transition: top .4s, left .4s, right .4s, transform .4s, width .4s;
        }
    }
    .stash-back-btn {
        padding: 20px 0;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: {color:Text};
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: none;
    }
    
    .stash-back-btn svg {
        fill: {color:Accent};
        -webkit-transition: .2s all;
        transition: .2s all;
    }

    .stash-border-right {
        right: 0;
    }

    .stash-post-meta svg {
         fill: {color:Accent}!important;
    }
    @media (max-width: 550px) {
        .stash-post-meta svg {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
            transform: scale(1.3);
        }
    }

    .close-modal svg g path {
        fill:{color:Accent};
    }
    
    svg .animated-circle {
        stroke:{color:Accent};
    }

    .stash-post-meta .close {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    @media (max-width: 550px) {
        .close-modal {
            top:20px;
            left:10px;
        }
        #stash-container {
            background: {color:Background};
        }
    }
    
    .stash-overlay {
        background:{color:Background};
    }
    .tmblr-iframe--desktop-logged-in-controls.iframe-controls--desktop {
        z-index: 1000000!important;
    }
    
    .post-navigation li, .post-navigation li, .post-navigation li span, .ps-options {
        background:{color:Text};
    }
    
    .post-navigation li a, .post-navigation li a, .post-navigation li span, .ps-options{
        color:{color:Background};
    }
    
    .post-navigation li:hover, .post-navigation li:hover, .post-navigation li:hover span, .ps-options:hover {
        background:{color:Background};
    }
    
    .post-navigation li:hover > a, .post-navigation li:hover > a, .post-navigation li:hover span, .ps-options:hover {
        color:{color:Text};
    }
    
    .post-navigation li:after, .ps-options:after {
        background:{color:Background};
        opacity:0.1;
        width:100%;
        height:1px;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:-1px;
        left:0;
    }
    
    #stash-preloader {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1000000;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: {color:Background};
    }
    #stash-preloader .loading-icon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        border: 0.25rem solid transparent;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 8px;
        animation-name: spin;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.15, 0.45, 0.85);
    }
    #stash-preloader .loading-icon, #ants-loader .loading-icon {
        border: 0.25rem solid transparent;
        border-top-color: {color:Accent};
    }
    
    {block:IfNotShowPostDate}
        .meta-date, .meta time {
            display:none !important;
        }
    {/block:IfNotShowPostDate}

    {block:IfNotShowPostMeta}
        .note-count, #stash-ants .meta, #stash-ants .post-meta .share, .meta, .share {
            display:none !important;
        }
    {/block:IfNotShowPostMeta}
  
    {block:IfNotShowPostShare}
        #stash-ants .post .post-share-parent, .stash-show-share {
            display:none;
        }
    {/block:IfNotShowPostShare}
    
    {block:IfNotShowPostLike}
        .post-like, .overlay .post-footer .post-like {
            display:none !important;
        }
    {/block:IfNotShowPostLike}
    
    {block:IfNotShowPostReblog}
        .post-reblog, .overlay .post-footer .post-reblog {
            display:none !important;
        }
    {/block:IfNotShowPostReblog}
    
    {block:IfNotShowPostTags}
        #stash-ants .post .tags, .tags, .the-tag {
            display:none !important;
        }
    {/block:IfNotShowPostTags}
    
    {block:IfNotShowPostCaption}
        #stash .post-photo .post-meta, #stash .post-photo .content, #stash .post-photoset .post-meta, #stash .post-photoset .content {
            display:none;
        }
        
        #stash .post-video .post-meta, #stash .post-video .content, #stash .post-audio .post-meta, #stash .post-audio .content {
            display:none;
        }
    {/block:IfNotShowPostCaption}
    
    {block:IfShowPostCaption}
        .overlay, .overlay-bg {
            display:none;
        }
    {/block:IfShowPostCaption}
    
    {block:IfNotShowPostNoteCount}
        #stash-ants .post .meta-notes, .note-count {
            display:none;
        }
    {/block:IfNotShowPostNoteCount}

    {block:IfNotShowRebloggedFrom}
        .reblogged-from {
            display:none;
        }
    {/block:IfNotShowRebloggedFrom}
    
    {block:IfNotShowPhotoOverlay}
        .overlay, .overlay-bg {
            display:none;
        }
    {/block:IfNotShowPhotoOverlay}
    
    {block:ifBannerOnlyNoPosts}
        .index .page-container {
            display:none;
        }
        body.tagged-page.index .page-container {
            display:block !important;
        }
        .arr-down {
            display:none;
        }
    {/block:ifBannerOnlyNoPosts}
    
    #banner p {
        font:{select:Banner Text Font Weight} {text:Banner Text Size} {block:IfBannerFont}"{text:Banner Font}",{/block:IfBannerFont} "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        {block:IfTypeKitBannerFont}
            font:{select:Banner Text Font Weight} {text:Banner Text Size} "{text:Typekit Banner Font}", "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        {/block:IfTypeKitBannerFont}
        color:{color:Banner Text};
        margin:0 auto 25px auto;
        width:100%;
    }
    .banner-text a {
        color:{color:Banner Text};
    }
    
    .navigation {
        font-weight:{select:Logo Font Weight};
    }

    .navigation a {
        color:{color:Header Text};
    }

    .banner-img {
        background:url({image:Banner Background}) center bottom no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
        background-position:center center;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height:100vh;
        width:100%;
        top:27px;
        left:0;
        z-index:-1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
        transition: opacity .8s linear,-webkit-transform 2.6s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
        transition: opacity .8s linear,transform 2.6s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
    }
    
    .mobile-banner-img {
        background:url({image:Mobile Banner Background}) center center no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
        background-position:center center;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height:100vh;
        width:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        z-index:-2;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
        transition: opacity .8s linear,-webkit-transform 2.6s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
        transition: opacity .8s linear,transform 2.6s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
    }
    
    @media (min-width:740px) {
        .mobile-banner-img {
            display:none;
        }
        
    }
    
    {block:IfBannerYoutubeVideoID}
        .banner-img, .mobile-banner-img {
            display:none;
        }
    {/block:IfBannerYoutubeVideoID}
    
    {block:IfBannerVimeoVideoID}
        @media (min-width:740px) {
            .banner-img, .mobile-banner-img {
                display:none;
            }
        }
    {/block:IfBannerVimeoVideoID}
    
    {block:IfBannerVimeoVideoID}
        @media (max-width:740px) {
            .banner-img, .mobile-banner-img {
                display:block;
            }   
            
            #banner-vimeo-video, .banner-video-options {
                display:none;
            }
        }
    {/block:IfBannerVimeoVideoID}
    
    .banner-center {
        max-width: {text:Banner Text Width};
    }
    .banner-text {
        font:{select:Banner Text Font Weight} {text:Banner Text Size} {block:IfBannerFont}"{text:Banner Font}",{/block:IfBannerFont} "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        {block:IfTypeKitBannerFont}
            font:{select:Banner Text Font Weight} {text:Banner Text Size} "{text:Typekit Banner Font}", "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        {/block:IfTypeKitBannerFont}
        transition:font 0.25s ease-out;
        color:{color:Banner Text};
    }
    
    @media (max-width:740px) {
        {block:ifmobilebannerbackgroundimage}
            .banner-img {
                display:none;
            }
        {/block:ifmobilebannerbackgroundimage}
        
        .banner-text {
            font:{select:Banner Text Font Weight} 22px  {block:IfBannerFont}"{text:Banner Font}",{/block:IfBannerFont} "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
            {block:IfTypeKitBannerFont}
                font:22px "{text:Typekit Banner Font}", "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
            {/block:IfTypeKitBannerFont}
        }
        
        #banner p {
            max-width:100%;
        }
        
        .banner-center {
            max-width:90%;
        }
    }
    
    {block:ifnotBannerVideoButtons}
        .banner-video-options {
            display:none;   
        }
    {/block:ifnotBannerVideoButtons}
    
    {block:ifBannerOverlay}
        .banner-youtube-video, #banner-vimeo-video, .banner-img, .mobile-banner-img {
            opacity:{text:Banner Overlay Opacity};  
        }
        #banner {
            background-color:black;
        }
    {/block:ifBannerOverlay}
    
    #banner a {
        color:{color:Banner Text};
    }
    
    #banner {
        background-color:{color:Banner Background};
    }   
    
    body.tagged-page #banner {
        display:none !important;
    }
    
    #banner.has-video, #banner.has-banner-image {
        display:block;
    }
    
    {block:ifMobileHideBanner}
        @media (max-width:740px) {
            #banner {
                display:none !important;
                opacity:0 !important;
                visibility:hidden !important;
                height:0 !important;
            }
        }
    {/block:ifMobileHideBanner}

    .banner-navigation a:hover {
        border-bottom: 1px solid {color:Banner Text};
    }
    
    {block:ifMobileHideSidebar}
        @media (max-width:740px) {
            #sidebar, .sidebar-toggle {
                display:none !important;
            }
        }
    {/block:ifMobileHideSidebar}
    
    .arr-down, .mute-button, .play-button, .banner-video-option, .banner-video-options {
        color:{color:Banner Text};
    }
    
    .logo, .logo a {
        font:{select:Logo Font Weight} {text:Logo Size}/40px {block:IfLogoFont}"{text:Logo Font}",{/block:IfLogoFont} "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        
        {block:IfTypeKitLogoFont}
            font:{select:Logo Font Weight} {text:Logo Size}/40px "{text:Typekit Logo Font}", "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        {/block:IfTypeKitLogoFont}
        
        color:{color:Logo};
        font-weight:{select:Logo Font Weight};
    }
    .sidebar-logo, .sidebar-logo a {
        font:{select:Logo Font Weight} 19px {block:IfLogoFont}"{text:Logo Font}",{/block:IfLogoFont} "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        
        {block:IfTypeKitLogoFont}
            font:{select:Logo Font Weight} 19px "{text:Typekit Logo Font}", "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
        {/block:IfTypeKitLogoFont}
    }

    .arr-down svg {
        fill:{color:Banner Text};
    }
    #sidebar .social-links a {
        color:{color:Header Text};
    }
    #sidebar .social-links a:hover {
        color:{color:Header Text};
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 740px) { 
        {block:ifmobilebannerbackgroundimage}
            .banner-img {
                display:none;
            }
        {/block:ifmobilebannerbackgroundimage}            
    
        .stash-overlay {
            background: {color:Background};
        }
    
        .logo a {
            font:{select:Logo Font Weight} 19px/40px {block:IfLogoFont}"{text:Logo Font}",{/block:IfLogoFont} "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
            {block:IfTypeKitLogoFont}
                font:{select:Logo Font Weight} 19px/40px "{text:Typekit Logo Font}", "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
            {/block:IfTypeKitLogoFont}
            width:auto;
        }
        
        #banner p {
            font:{select:Banner Text Font Weight} 18px {block:IfBannerFont}"{text:Banner Font}",{/block:IfBannerFont} "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
            {block:IfTypeKitBannerFont}
                font:{select:Banner Text Font Weight} 18px "{text:Typekit Banner Font}", "{select:Font}", Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
            {/block:IfTypeKitBannerFont}
            max-width:100%;
        }
        #header {
            background:{color:Header Background};
            height:60px;
            line-height:60px;
        }
        
        .navigation, .header-social {
            display:none;
        }
        
        #header a, .logo a, .logo, .sidebar-toggle {
            color:{color:Header Text};
        }
        
        .close-mobile-modal svg g {
            fill:{color:Header Text};
        }
    }
    
    .sidebar-toggle #hamburger > div:after, .sidebar-toggle #hamburger > div:before {
        background:{color:Header Text};
    }
        
     /* Customize Help */
    
    .demo-note {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right:0;
        background: black;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        z-index: 999999;
        width:100%;
        max-width:240px;
        opacity:0;
        visibility:hidden;
        transform:translateY(100%);
        transition:all 0.3s ease;
        opacity:0.5;
    }
    
    .demo-note:hover {
        opacity:1;
    }
    
    .demo-note.visible {
        opacity:1;
        visibility:visible;
        transform:translateY(0);
    }
    
    .demo-note nav {
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-size:16px;
    }
    
    .demo-note nav ul {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    
    .demo-note nav ul li {
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
        width:100%;
    }
    
    .demo-note nav ul li a {
        padding:14px;
        display:block;
    }
    
    .demo-note  a {
        color:white;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    
    .demo-note nav .im {
        font-size:11px;
        margin-left:3px;
        transition:all 0.2s;
    }
    
    .get-started-toggle {
        background:url('https://static.tumblr.com/jzzkxgh/Nn0qi7lym/glitter-og.gif');
    }
    
    .get-started-toggle a {
        color:white;
    }
    
    .demo-toggle.open .im {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
        transform:rotate(180deg);
    }
    
    .remove-stash-credit {
        background:white url('https://static.tumblr.com/jzzkxgh/Ud7ppcbpu/remove-stash-credit.gif');
        background-position:center center;
    }
    
    .remove-stash-credit a {
        color:black;
    }

    .remove-stash-credit a:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    
    .demo-overlay {
        color:white;
        height:0;
        -webkit-transition:opacity 0.8s ease, height 0.8s ease, visibility, 0.8s ease ;
        transition:opacity 0.8s ease, height 0.8s ease, visibility, 0.8s ease;
        opacity:0;
        visibility:hidden;
    }

    .demo-overlay.open {
        margin-top:10px;
        height:auto;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.8s ease;
        transition:all 0.8s ease;
        opacity:1;
        visibility:visible;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .demo-overlay p {
        margin-bottom:10px;
        font-size:13px;
        line-height:1.3;
    }
    
    .demo-overlay p a {
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    
    .demo-overlay img {
        margin-top: 6px;
        max-width:95%;
    }
    
    body.tagged-page .post {
        opacity:1;
        visibility:visible;
    }
    
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is 100% the answer, but I think the main issue might be this:

```
.note-count, #stash-ants .meta, #stash-ants .post-meta .share, .meta, .share {
   display:none !important;
}
```

I don't think that is targeting the post-meta field which you want to hide.

It should be

```
.note-count, 
#stash-ants .meta, 
#stash-ants .post-meta // remove .share from this line; 
.meta, 
.share {
   display:none !important;
}
```

In addition I believe your document height is being calculated by javascript so it will add space depending on the visible elements.

I assuming you never want to show this data in desktop and mobile this should be all you need. Otherwise you have to write media queries. I can update the answer if so, but it seems as though the post-meta is hidden in desktop also.

The other thing you could try is to add: `height: 0` to your css selector, this will ensure js will not calculate the height for these elements, but I cannot test it, so good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to hide the meta data by targeting the selectors individually. After some trial and error I targeted `*` and added `margin: 0;` to remove the spacing.